# On My iPhone folders, how to create a folder for my app? [iOS 13]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I am trying to create a folder for my app in the Files app for access when i want to save a file from my app

In iOS 12 and earlier i could achieve this by enabling

`Application supports iTunes file sharing` and `Supports opening documents in place` as shown below

[image]

Since updating to iOS 13, the same folder that used to show up in iOS 12 no-longer shows.

What has changed and how can i get this resolved in iOS 13?

I use the extension below to save files:

```
extension WebViewController:  URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

        // create destination URL with the original pdf name
        guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else { return }
        let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        // delete original copy
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
        // copy from temp to Document
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
             DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2){
            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.fileName, destinationURL], applicationActivities: nil)
                if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
                    if let popOver = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
                        popOver.sourceView = self.view
                        popOver.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
                        popOver.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
                        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                else{
                    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I store docx, pdf, xlsx. But even before storing a file, normally the 'Save to files' option would reveal a folder inside the files app with my app name

Comment: I have edited my question to show how i'm saving files

Comment: `let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]` That is not the Documents directory. The files app shows your Documents directory.

Comment: is there an explanation for this working in iOS 12?

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the answer to the specific problem above,

Updating to iOS 13.1 seems to fix this issue, so i'm not sure if this was a bug of some sort