# Where can I find the MyDocuments folder on iPhone Simulator?

Tags: ios, file, xamarin, xamarin.ios, file-handling

I created a text file named *Write.txt* in the Documents folder in a Xamarin.iOS app. After that I was able to read its content to the console.

```
var documents = 
 Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "Write.txt");

File.WriteAllText(filename, "Write this text into a file");
var text = File.ReadAllText(filename);

Console.WriteLine(text);  // prints out correctly
```

The problem is, that I can't found this file on the iPhone simulator's Files app. There is no Documents folder anywhere, and I don't get any results if I search for the filename.

(Yes, I'm new in iOS, so sorry if the question is stupid :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Building Great Document-based Apps in iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/229).

If you want to see it in the files app, you’ll want to set the following value in your `Info.plist`:

- “Supports Document Browser” (`UISupportsDocumentBrowser`)

Or

- “Application supports iTunes file sharing” (`UIFileSharingEnabled`); and
- “Supports opening documents in place” (`LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`)

Comment: That’s funny, because I tested both of these on iOS 13 before posting and it worked fine, showing the file in the app’s Documents folder within the Files app.

Comment: My document based app has UIFileSharingEnabled and LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace and it no longer appears in the Files app. I've seen other questions asking about the same thing. There must be some new further requirement but I haven't worked out what it is.

Comment: It's a custom file type. Here is another example of the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173265/ios-13-1-cannot-save-file-to-app-directory

Comment: Here's another one; the OP claims this was fixed in an iOS update but that is not the case for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125994/on-my-iphone-folders-how-to-create-a-folder-for-my-app-ios-13

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I created a custom file type (but none of the document-based app scaffolding, just a file with a custom extension) and a `txt` file, and when I look in the “On my iPhone” folder in Files, I see both of these on iOS 13.1 simulator and 13.1.3 device. (I don’t have any 13.0 device and see no such simulator. ☹️) If you can direct me to MCVE, I’m more than happy to take a look.

Comment: Whoa! In desperation I shut my phone down and restarted it, and not only my app but a whole bunch of apps showed up in the Files browser! I wonder how much that's behind other statements of the same issue. Sorry for the noise but this was a big surprise.

Comment: Well, now I can't get iCloud to work with this app. Sigh.

Comment: OK well I got _that_ to work by signing out of iCloud and back in again. It's like in iOS 13 nothing works until you smash it with a wrench.

Comment: Confirmed that it is an iOS 13 issue. Rebooting sometimes help. Searching inside the Files app sometimes help.

Answer (score 2):

I just run your code and it all works well on my side. The file you written to was successfully opened. I guess you might have some wrong step when opening the folder, let me show you how to do it:

1.I run your code and then print the file path(the **filename** in your code), on my side it is:

```
/Users/myName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0F06FD18-4307-4102-8A30-5EB017A4BD26/data/Containers/Data/Application/20A0294B-36C5-484F-8BD1-B69B977BA378/Documents/Write.txt
```

2.Go to `your mac` --> select `Finder` --> Then open the `Go menu` --> Click `Go to Folder`

[image: screenShot]

3.Paste your path to the `text box`:

[image]

4.Click `Go` and you will see the file:

[image]

Some folders are hidden in your system so you can't see them when search for the filename. Feel free to ask me if you have any question.